# Unit testing angular directive that wraps jquery lib

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, magnific-popup

I have a small angular app that displays lightboxes. I didn't find anything appropriate (look good on mobile) made for angular, so I settled on magnific-popup.
Magnific popup uses jquery to initialize popups:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.image-link').magnificPopup({type:'image'})
```

I have written a minimal directive which I use to get this working with angular:

```
angular.module('myapp').directive 'magnificHelper', ($timeout) ->
  restrict: 'A'
  link: (scope, element, attr) ->
    if (scope.$last == true)
      $timeout ->
        element.parent().find('.image-link').magnificPopup
          type:'image'
          gallery: {enabled: true}
```

This works well, but I am unsure how to write a unit test for this code. I have tried to find an answer online and I guess this must be a fairly common problem, but I didn't find any relevant solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to test, a basic test could check if `$last` is defined, e.g.:

```
'use strict';
describe('magnificHelper', function() {
  var $compile,$rootScope, $scope,$timeout, template;

  beforeEach(module('myapp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    $timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
    $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    template = $compile("<div magnificHelper> </div>")($scope);
    $scope.$digest();
  }));

  /*
   *
   * Tests
   *
   */
  describe('Test something', function() {
    it('should test something', function() {
      expect(template).toBeDefined()
      expect($scope.last).toBeDefined()
    });
  });
});
```

I guess that you can also do something like `$scope.magnificPopup = element.parent().find('.image-link').magnificPopup`and then inside your test check the `$scope.magnificPopup` value